# How to write a new csv by reading the data from another csv using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a dictionary like this:

```
data_heading = {'Date': [(3,2)],
                'Rate': [(3,3)],
                'Product': [(3,7)]}
```

the KEY defines the heading of column in csv file, the VALUE defines the `[(row number, col number)]`
I want to read the data, starting from a specific LINE, and specific COLUMN, till the end of csv file.
After reading the contents of file I want to write a new csv of the read data.
I am much confused in this problem, I have tried a long long code to do so, but still unable to write such file.
I'll be Thankful for your kind support. Please help me.
I have read the data and stored it in a list like:

```
data = ['Date', '2013-03-01', '2013-03-01', '2013-03-01', 'Rate', '$ 50', '$ 60', '$ 70', 'Product', 'MOBILE', 'DVD', 'TV']
```

but i am unable to write it in a csv. . .

Comment: Are you aware of the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv) module?

Comment: yeah I Know how to read and write a csv but to fetch the DESIRED data from a csv seems much difficult to me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (untested since you didn't provide full code+data):

```
import csv

data_heading = {'Date': [(3,2)],
            'Rate': [(3,3)],
            'Product': [(3,7)]}

rdr = csv.reader(open(csvpath, 'rb'))
columns = [{key:row[pos[0][1]] for key,pos in data_heading.items()} for row in rdr]
# finally trim to desired row startpoints:
data = {key:[col[key] for col in columns[pos[0][0]:]] for key,pos in  data_heading.items()}
print data
```

It's a little gnarly because your `data_heading` is in a slightly awkward format. If you have freedom to change that, the code can be made more readable.

You can do the CSV writing after that - `data` should be a simple enough dict to write out.

Comment: Thanks the data now seems much clearer :) now I hope to find a simple way to write it in a csv :) and thanks again!